# Mapping 3 Java Beans into 1

Tags: java, spring, mapping, javabeans

I have a requirement to produce a DTO from a variety of different sources. Each source has been populated into a DTO so I just have to map all 3 beans into 1 bean.  Each field has a priority list where field A should be populate from Source 1, if that is null then source 2 and if that is null source 3. But the order of the sources changes for each field of the bean.

```
| Field | Priority 1    | Priorirty 2   | Priority 3    | 
| A     | Source 1      | Source 2      | Source 3      |
| B     | Source 3      | Source 1      | Source 2      |
| C     | Source 1      | Source 3      | Source 2      |
```

Is that any good frameworks/libraries that can help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

JMapper can help you, it exposes the RelationalJMapper class that permits to apply many to one e and one to many relations, for more info go to [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/jmapper-framework/wiki/ExplicitRelations#Many_to_One) page